# Disable the floating action button programmatically

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I have a floating action button, I want to deactivate or disable it for guest users (my guest users are when the `userId == null`).

I tried to use `if...else`, but it did not work and the floating action button is still active for guest user.

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class inset extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String USER_ID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inset);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call setClickable to set fab can click or can not click

```
        if (userId == null)
            fab.setClickable(false);
        else fab.setClickable(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable `FloatingActionButton`by setting `visibility` to `GONE`. Here's the code.

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton; 
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.View; import android.widget.Toast;

public class inset extends AppCompatActivity { 

private String USER_ID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inset);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);


    if(userID==null) fab.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
    else fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();

        }
    });
}
}
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple way to achieve this based on check of `USER_ID == null`

1. You can simply toggle the visibility of FAB by `fab.setVisibility`
2. You can disable the click on FAB by `fab.setClickable`
3. You can disable the FAB state by `fab.setEnabled`
4. You can check the condition inside `onClick` block and show the message accordingly to user.

I think you should go with 1st or 4th approach as user experience is better in these cases. Either user don't see the button or he gets the proper error message when he is not eligible to trigger that event.